# The Cauchy Principal value of integral

Tags: complex-analysis

The given integral is

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(x^2+1)} dx$$

$\text{The solution i tried}-$Here we can see we have three singularities $-\iota,\iota\ ,0$  i am not getting how to take that $- \iota$ singularity in counter .how to solve further .please provide hint.

Thankyou

Comment: The result should be $$\frac{(e-1) \pi }{e}$$

Comment: yes,but how can i get this answer?

Comment: Note that the singularity at $0$ is removable, and you don't have to use every single singularity in order to apply the residue theorem.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou so the only singularity is $\iota $ and $-\iota$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let$$f(a)=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (ax)}{x(x^2+1)}dx$$
$$f'(a)=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos (ax)}{x^2 +1}dx$$
$$f''(a)=-2\int_0^\infty\frac{x\sin (ax)}{x^2 + 1}dx$$

Then what can we get from $f''(a)-f(a)$  ?